# Check for Updates every 10 Minutes and make Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an app which downloads a JSON-file from a server and displays the information in a listview, nothing spectacular. But I would like to make it a little bit more useful. What I would like to do is download the file every 10 or x minutes and check if something changed. If something changed I would like to make a notification. So it's basically something like the mail apps where the apps checks every x minutes in the background if new mails have arrived. But I really don't know how to make something like a background activity which checks the file constantly even if my app isn't active. I've read about the AlarmManager but it looks like it doesn't work the way I want. So do you have any tips how I could manage it?

Comment: What is wrong with Alarm Manager?

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken it always starts my app. But I don't want it being brought to the front.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have two options: Using Alarm Manager or using a Service.

If you don't want to provide a user interface for what you want to do, then regardless of the method you use you would end up using a Service anyway. I explain:

If you use a standalone Service, you're responsible for instantiating it and terminating it, you need to handle it's lifecycle, and having a timer that fires every 10 minutes to do your job. Additionally you need to consider the cases where the Service gets killed for memory reasons.

If you use Alarm Manager, you can pass a Service in the intent. The Service doesn't need a user interface and would just be responsible to do the job at startup and ending itself after finishing.

I would use the Alarm Manager with a service, check [here for an example](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.mx/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html).

Comment: Thanks, I`ve done it this way. But I have now the problem that the service will be run only once. I have a AlarmManager with setRepeating which fires a BroadcastReceiver which calls a Service to do the job. It works once and then never again.

Comment: There must be a problem with how you configure the alarms. I'd suggest you to post a new question with your new issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, consider using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) rather than have all the clients poll the server over and over again. This will save battery power and server load.

If it has to be a plain HTML server then use Alarm Manager as Merlevede explains, and also use [HTTP If-Modified-Since: date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#if-modified-since) or an [HTTP Etag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) to check if the file was modified before downloading it.